Facing Error 'createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element' in running tests of React 18 app
I recently upgraded my React App into React 18.2.0. and when trying to use the @testing-library/react library to run the tests, I got the error: createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
In my index.js file I`m using this code:
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
);

And when trying to test the rendering using the testing library and jest, some components are working and others are showing the error.
Please support!
I already set the root element in the index.html file as:
<div id="root" class="wrapper"></div>

I`m expecting an advise on how to resolve this error, and what may be the reasons behind this error.

Does this answer your question? createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element in React Test file

that post is not solving my error. I tried to Replace "root.render();" with with "render(); " which is Imported from @testing-library/react. but still getting the same error.
